# rolling_window in pandas 19, using custom shapes

Tags: python, pandas

I used to have in my code a pd.rolling_window(s,window=np.array(l),....) while using 0.17.
The new series.rolling(window,win_type), now doesn't support anything other than ints on window, and win_type is limited to a fixed set of shapes.

How can I migrate my old custom rolling_window mean to 0.19 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems `Rolling` lost the custom window functionality. Luckily, it still retains its `Rolling.apply` method.

If you want a special window mean, one way to do this is to take any normalized array (sum of elements = 1) and `numpy.correlate` (which is just combined array multiplication and sum) it in the `.apply` method:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,0,0,0,0],'b':[0,0,0,1,0,0]})
>>> print df
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  0  0
3  0  1
4  0  0
5  0  0
>>> my_array = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> # Below implements a weighted mean
>>> df.rolling(len(my_array)).apply(lambda column: np.correlate(column,my_array/sum(my_array)))
          a         b
0       NaN       NaN
1       NaN       NaN
2  0.333333  0.000000
3  0.166667  0.500000
4  0.000000  0.333333
5  0.000000  0.166667
>>> # Same thing, but thanks to '[0]' we can have min_periods < len(my_array)
>>> df.rolling(len(my_array),min_periods=1).apply(lambda column: np.correlate(column,my_array/sum(my_array))[0])
          a         b
0  0.000000  0.000000
1  0.500000  0.000000
2  0.333333  0.000000
3  0.166667  0.500000
4  0.000000  0.333333
5  0.000000  0.166667
```

Edit: Numpy also just has a `average()` method with a weight argument. Go with that if just doing a simple weighted average.